# multi project swagger documentation in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I have micro-services developed using NodeJS. I need to centralize all APIs, but to avoid any confusion, I want each micro-service documented on a separate page. My question is, is there a way to create multiple pages in Swagger using NodeJS? Each page should have links to other pages.

I found a solution using [React](https://empire-doc-portal.netlify.app/), but I was hoping to accomplish this using only NodeJS and Swagger. I've seen many similar questions, but they often pertain to Java and Spring Boot instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use swagger-jsdoc and swagger-ui-express packages in NodeJS to do this.

```
const express = require('express');
const swaggerJsDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');

const app = express();

const swaggerOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    info: {
      title: 'Microservice API',
      version: '1.0.0',
    },
  },
  apis: ['app.js'], // path to the API docs
};

const swaggerDocs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerOptions);
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs));
```

Comment: Are you sure it provides multiple page solution? Because it seems to me that it's just multiple endpoints from same project, and all they are on same page